# Shinyapp with HTML Editor

Tags: r, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I would like to have a HTML Editor in a Shiny App and I found the CKEditor, which is free and can be installed on my machine or used via internet. I want to create a simple Texteditorinterface for non programming people. The text should be visible after a completion.

Unfortunately I can't get it to work that a HTML Editor arises. I want to use the online Inline Mode.

I can only see the non relevant UI part but not an html editor layer.

Here is my actual Code:

```
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader( title = "Name")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  
  sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarID",
              menuItem("Landing Page", tabName = "landing_page", icon = icon("th"))
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  
  tags$head(    
    tags$script("https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/37.1.0/inline/ckeditor.js"),
  ),
  
  useShinyjs(),
  tabItems(
    
    # Landing Page content
    tabItem(tabName = "landing_page",
            h2("Test Head"),
            tags$div(id="editor", list(
              br(),
              p("Test test")
            )),
            tags$script(HTML("InlineEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );"
            ))
    )
  )
)

ui <-  dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = "blue")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$editor <- renderText({
    
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The goal is something like this in a shinydashboardmanager app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor 5 - Inline editor</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/37.1.0/inline/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Inline editor</h1>
    <div id="editor">
        <p>This is some sample content.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        InlineEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for your help